# SQL Server - Set a timeout / automatic ROLLBACK on TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, locking, rollback

With `TRANSACTION`, is there a way to have it `ROLLBACK` automatically after X number of seconds? This way you'd prevent accidentally leaving a `TRANSACTION` open and locking the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get Tools>properties >Designers > table and data base designers --- then set "transaction time-out after" upper than 90s or more than.
[image: Tools>properties]

Comment: Does this perform a `ROLLBACK` if the time is exceeded?

Comment: you have two way.
1. set time by second... (If the execution is not complete and finish time for query is rollback)
2.you can set none time (isn't recommend) Unchecked "Override connection string time-out value for table designer update" --- not rollback for unlimited (automatically- you can stop manually or use wait function in query )